# Displaying file names with a certain number of characters in command line

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

I need to list all text files on the C drive whose names are seven characters long. I tried the following command

```
DIR ???????.txt
```

However, this command displayed files with seven characters and less. Which command could I use to only display files with seven characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard `?` matches any character at most once, so `dir ???????.txt` will match any .txt-file with an extension preceded by at most seven characters. There is no wildcard that matches any character exactly once that `dir` directly supports, but the command's output can be piped into `findstr`, which supports regular expressions.

In this case, `dir /B | findstr /R "^.......\.txt"` will do the trick.

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for thankyou you have been a huge help

Comment: So then this is wrong? http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html "`? Match any ONE character`", or , http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true , it say ? substitute _one_ character, not "at most one".

Comment: As far as I know, the ?-wildcard has matched zero or one character ever since MS-DOS. Likewise, the character `?` is used in regular expressions to match the preceding element zero or one times, but after some digging, it seems there is more to it. Apperently, `?` will only match zero characters when it preceeds either another wildcard, a dot or the end of a string, in Windows 7, that is. How convenient!

Comment: I love this solution. It took me a while though to figure out how I can use it with subdirectories (dir /b /s) because it also returned files like c:\test\aa.txt (yes, *test\aa* has 7 characters too). I found the solution in the commandline:   dir /B /s| findstr /R "\\[^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\]\.txt$"

Comment: @MarcksThomas Ok, thanks. Thought so, but the "documentation" I found was a bit vague/misleading.

Comment: maybe empty string is a character for them. but they should write it better and give 2-3 examples along with find str

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a batch file that examines the output of `dir ???????.txt` and echoes only the files that have 7 characters (11, including .txt).

```
@ECHO OFF

REM --- Call Subroutine for all files of Len 1 - 7 characters ---
For /f "delims=*" %%a in ('dir "c:\???????.txt" /b') do Call :CheckLen %%~nxa

REM --- End Batchfile ---
Goto :eof

:CheckLen
  REM --- Place Filename in Variable FNAME ---
  Set FName=%*

  REM --- IF Valiable FName <> First 10 characters of FName, FName has  ---
  REM --- 11 Characters (7 + .txt). Echo Output ---
  if NOT "%FName%"=="%FName:~0,10%" Echo %FName%
```

Note: In line `'dir "c:\???????.txt" /b'` ,add `/s` if you want also to search the subdirectories of C:. This will probably take a long time without output.

Comment: thanks this seems to work as i'm new to scripting is their a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
DIR /b /s | findstr /r /i "\\.......\.txt$"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Instead of just posting a line of code, please explain what it does as well. [Edit] your post to add more info. Thanks.